# EXPRESS NODE petición GET siempre me regresa un vacío

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy comenzando a programar una api y cuando mando una petición siempre me manda vacío. No tengo error siempre me manda un 200 no sé que parte del código este incompleta o mal escrita para que siempre me mande un vacio.

controllador usuario:

```
const usuarioControlador={}

usuarioControlador.getUsuario=async(req,res)=>{
    const usuarios=await Usuario.find()
    res.json(usuarios)
}
module.exports=usuarioControlador
```

Rutas usuario:

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()

const usuario=require('../controladores/usuario')
router.get('/',usuario.getUsuario)

module.exports=router
```

index.js :

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express=require('express')
const cors=require('cors')
const morgan=require('morgan')
const app=express()
const {mongoose}=require('./conexion')


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan('dev'))
puerto=4000
app.use(express.json())
app.listen(puerto,()=>{console.log('servidor en: '+puerto)})

app.use('/api/usuario',require('./rutas/usuario'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifica tu controlador de esto:

```js
const usuarioControlador={}

usuarioControlador.getUsuario=async(req,res)=>{
    const usuarios=await Usuario.find()
    res.json(usuarios)
}
module.exports=usuarioControlador
```

A algo como esto:

```js
const getUsuario = async(req,res) => {
    const usuarios= await Usuario.find()
    res.json(usuarios)
} 

module.exports = { getUsuario }
```

Y en el archivo rutas aplica `destructuring`:

```js
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()

const { getUsuario } = require('../controladores/usuario')
router.get('/',getUsuario )

module.exports=router
```

---

#### EDIT:

Modifica tu `index.js`:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express=require('express')
const cors=require('cors')
const morgan=require('morgan')
const {mongoose}=require('./conexion')
const rutasAA = require('./rutas/usuario')

const app=express()


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(rutasAA)

app.listen(4000)
```

Comment: @Isanchezo Hice el cambio a los archivos y siguen mandando el error. Crees que sea del modelo?

Comment: Creo que puede ser en el `.use()` de las rutas. Ahí lo edité; también lo del puerto, la variable ni estaba definida. Intenta nuevamente.

Comment: @Isanchezo Hice también la prueba y tampoco quedo me sigue lanzando lo mismo, ya no se donde sea el error.

Comment: Bueno, si te manda vacío sin error entonces el `.find()` debe ser el tema, trata de ver eso.

Answer (score 0):

Y si haces un console.log() antes de buscar un usuario ? para verificar que la peticion llegue al res. Si haces la peticion en el local y hace status 200 y se imprime el console.log significa que la peticion funciona pero lo que no devuelve nada es el usuarios.find(), tambien podes imprimir a ver que te trae el metodo find(), capas no te trae nada entonces devuelve vacio.